# How do I compare rows across sheets in Excel?

Tags: excel

I've read through some of the topics that were similar to mine but I couldn't find an answer for what I need. Perhaps it is a logic problem on my part.

I have two sheets with identical data however they come from two different sources. I need to compare rows from 1 sheet to rows of the 2nd sheet to find out what is missing or different so I can fix.

I have columns A - M which has the data points. I then have column N which I concatenated all the columns together and compared them to other sheet doing the same thing so I could find the Non-matching. Out of 40,000 records I have 6100 that do not match.

What I am trying to do is compare the whole row (or the concatenated) and find out what value is different between the two. I was attempting to do this by IF with a VLookup and nested IFs but this didn't turn out correct because I wasn't getting it to compare the same value from the same Row plus I ran out of allotted nesting space. I was thinking a match,index system might work. I need some help!

Edit:
To be more clear the rows do not line up. What I have to do is make sure all the rows from sheet "1" are in sheet "2" but not all of sheet "2" need to be in "1". Basically I need this -

From sheet "1" find the value in cell A1 in sheet "2" A:A. Then match B1-N1 to that same row (whatever row it is). If possible I'd like to identify either by highlighting or having a word such as "Mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

I would use a VBA solution. If the number of rows are the same for each sheet and you are comparing row 1 with row 1, etc. then:

1) Loop through each row and concatenate the rows' cells for each sheet.

2) Apply the clean and trim function to the results.

3) Compare the results.

4) If they match, move to the next row.

5) If they don't match, loop through each cell of the row range to find the ones that differ and capture it somehow.

6) Print the results somewhere.

OR

Put the range values of each sheet into two arrays and compare the arrays (faster).

I'm certain there's a better way but that would be my approach, at least.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time explaining exactly what I need. Let's say my row in sheet a consists of A B C D E F. I then concat and get ABCDEF. I compared this to Sheet 2 to find out if it had an ABCDEF. If it did not, the next step I need is to find if it has an "A". If it has an A then I need to find if that row that has an "A" if the next column in that row has a "B" because it is possible to have a 1 or a Q or anything else. If it has a B then go to 3rd column and so forth does that make sense?

Comment: @ChristopherWeber Yes, it makes perfect sense. That is what I am saying above, only do it with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a new sheet and in use each cell to do a cell by cell comparison across the sheets.  i.e. in new sheet cell a1 put `=value(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1)`  That give you a 1 where they're the same and a zero where they differ.

If you want you can set the column n on an original sheet to be the sum of the same row on the new sheet for easy reference.